# Rotate parts of multidimensional array

Tags: c#, matrix, multidimensional-array, rotation

I need to be able to rotate a section of an multidimensional array by declaring the range and direction.

Say I have an array of int:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[13, 14, 15, 16]
```

If I have a range from [2,2] to [3,3] and rotation Clockwise I would get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 15, 11]
[13, 14, 16, 12]
```

and if I then applied the range [0,1] to [2,3] and rotation Counter Clockwise I would get:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[7, 15, 16, 8]
[6, 10, 14, 11]
[5, 9, 13, 12]
```

The array will always be a matrix NxN (2*2,3*3,4*4..). Just rotating the matrix is not a problem but Im having problem doing it with just a section of it inside the matrix. How would I do this in C#?

Answer (score 0):

It reminds me of [this hackerrank problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/matrix-rotation-algo).

I don's see what are your specific problems - you can take this sub-matrix as an independent object and just rotate it.

For example consider the following algorithm:

1. Consider your matrix as a set of `'circuits'`.
2. Take these `'circuits'` on by one.
3. For each circuit apply rotation - don't forget to check if you `number of rotations% circuit perimeter = 0` (rotation is invariant in this case)
4. For each integer in a `'circuit'` just calculate it's new `position` (some simple math upon matrix indexes).

After all circuits of your submatrix are rotated you got your result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy some rows and swap them with columns. you may need to reverse them in some cases.

Code below solves your problem with example you give. note that this code only rotates outer circle. for example if rotating circle is 4x4 the inner circle 2x2 will not rotate. but you should get the idea.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[,] array = new int[4, 4]
    {
        {1, 2, 3, 4},
        {5, 6, 7, 8},
        {9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16}
    };

    Rotate(array, 2, 2, 3, 3, true);
    Rotate(array, 1, 0, 3, 2, false);

    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
        {
            Console.Write(array[i, j] + "  ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

private static void Rotate(int[,] array, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, bool clockwise)
{
    int[] r1 = CopyFromRow(array, x1, y1, x2 - x1 + 1);
    int[] r2 = CopyFromRow(array, x2, y1, x2 - x1 + 1);

    int[] c1 = CopyFromColumn(array, x1, y1, y2 - y1 + 1);
    int[] c2 = CopyFromColumn(array, x1, y2, y2 - y1 + 1);

    if (clockwise)
    {
        Array.Reverse(c1);
        Array.Reverse(c2);

        CopyToColumn(array, r1, x1, y2);
        CopyToColumn(array, r2, x1, y1);

        CopyToRow(array, c1, x1, y1);
        CopyToRow(array, c2, x2, y1);
    }
    else
    {
        Array.Reverse(r1);
        Array.Reverse(r2);

        CopyToColumn(array, r1, x1, y1);
        CopyToColumn(array, r2, x1, y2);

        CopyToRow(array, c1, x2, y1);
        CopyToRow(array, c2, x1, y1);
    }
}

private static void CopyToColumn(int[,] array, int[] row, int x1, int y1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < row.Length; i++)
    {
        array[x1 + i, y1] = row[i];
    }
}

private static void CopyToRow(int[,] array, int[] col, int x1, int y1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < col.Length; i++)
    {
        array[x1, y1 + i] = col[i];
    }
}


private static int[] CopyFromColumn(int[,] array, int x1, int y1, int length)
{
    int[] row = new int[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        row[i] = array[x1 + i, y1];
    }

    return row;
}

private static int[] CopyFromRow(int[,] array, int x1, int y1, int length)
{
    int[] col = new int[length];

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        col[i] = array[x1, y1 + i];
    }

    return col;
}
```